# Using branch() in Simmer for R

Tags: r

I am starting to use Simmer, barely getting my head around it at the moment and always struggle to use written documentation over practical examples.

I am trying to model a process with 2 resources, imagine a post office.

1. Customer approaches payment counter, hands over item and makes payment. This takes 15 seconds.
2. 90% of the items go straight into the storage container and exit the model.
3. 10% of the items go to a packaging station. The packaging takes 30 seconds, once complete the item exits the model.
4. If the packaging queue reaches 5 then the payment counter stops. It only restarts once the packaging queue goes under 5.

I believe branch is what I want to use but need some help in how to apply it, my very simple model is below

```
    env <- simmer("model")
env

traj <- trajectory(name = "item") %>% 
  seize("payment",1) %>% 
  timeout(function() rnorm(1,15)) %>% 
  release("payment",1) %>%
  
  seize("package",1) %>%
  timeout(function() rnorm(1,30)) %>% 
  release("package",1)

env %>%
  add_resource("payment",1) %>% 
  add_resource("package",1) %>% 
  add_generator(name_prefix = "test",
                trajectory = traj,
                distribution = function() rnorm(1,15))

env
env %>% run(until = 500)
```

as always any help is eternally appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, branching is the solution. In the branch
function, "option" can be used as a condition. I checked if the queue size of packaging counter is greater than 4, and if yes, I set the payment capacity to zero so it does not take any new customers. I added a few logs so the simulation can be monitored and validated easier. I suggest adding more attributes to double-check everything.

```
stor_cont_deter <- function(){
  x = runif(1,0,1)
  ifelse(x <= .1, 1, 0)
  }

load_to_container_traj <- trajectory() %>%
  log_("packaging_skipped") %>% 
  release("payment",1)

traj <- trajectory(name = "item") %>% 
  log_(function() {paste("start_time: ", now(test))})  %>%
  seize("payment",1) %>% 
  timeout(function() rnorm(1,15)) %>% 
  log_("finished_payment") %>% 
  branch(
    stor_cont_deter, continue = F,
    load_to_container_traj
  ) %>%
  log_("packaging_not_skipped") %>% 
  release("payment",1) %>%
  log_(function() {paste("package_queue_size: ", get_queue_count(test, "package"))})  %>%
  branch(
    function() ifelse(get_queue_count(test, "package") > 4, 1, 0),
    continue = T,
    trajectory() %>%
    log_("payment_stopped") %>% 
    set_capacity("payment", 0) %>% 
    log_(function() {paste("payment_cap: ", get_capacity(test, "payment"))})
  ) %>%
  seize("package",1) %>%
  timeout(function() rnorm(1,30)) %>%
  log_("finished_packing") %>% 
  release("package",1) %>% 
  log_(function() {paste("package_queue_size2: ", get_queue_count(test, "package"))})  %>%
  branch(
    function() ifelse(get_queue_count(test, "package") <= 4, 1, 0),
    continue = T,
    trajectory() %>% 
    log_("payment_can_start") %>% 
    set_capacity("payment", 1)
  )



test <- simmer("env") %>%
  add_resource("payment",1) %>% 
  add_resource("package",1) %>% 
  add_generator(name_prefix = "test",
                trajectory = traj,
                distribution = function() rnorm(1,15))

set.seed(78)
runsim <- test %>% run(until = 500)
```